# Missing LUKS passphrase from login.keyring

Tags: fedora, keychain

The passphrase for my external HD (which I randomly generated and foolishly never wrote down) was stored in my Fedora 21 keychain (`~/.local/share/keyrings/login.keyring`). I used to be able to see it under the "Login" section of the "Passwords and Keys" app.

However, starting yesterday, my computer was asking me for the passphrase whenever I plugged the drive in. I went to "Passwords and Keys", and discovered that the passphrase was no longer there. The `login.keyring` file shows that it was last modified 2 days ago, but I haven't used the computer for anything but web browsing for the last week or so, so I don't know how this modification could have occurred.

- Is it possible that it is still in the file, but is just not being
  read by the system for some reason?
- If it is not in the file, is there any way to retrieve it by
  forensically reading the bytes around the file, a filesystem journal,
  or any other means?

Comment: to part 1: not likely its more likely that a background update of a package made that method no longer available (not to mention it is Very bad practice anyways)  to part 2: if you made a worthy pass you best bet is a older backup as it won't be a trivial task in time or effort if even possible at this point.